# Mongoose get all data from base? find() method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to find all data from my modal but as a result, I got this:

```
{
    "error": "User.find is not a function"
}
```

How looks my modal:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.set("debug", true);

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  ...
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;

//modal User.js
```

My endpoint to get all Users in my case is next:

```
const User = "../../models/User";

const router = Router();
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    if (!users) throw Error("No users exist");
    res.json(users);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: e.message });
  }
});
```

Other methods like `findOne` or `save()` works very well.

From `mongoose debug`
`Mongoose: users.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })`
Why is this? As this happens, my modal name base is plural. `users` I don't from where that comes.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the exact problem like whether it's setting index or fetching all records using find?

Comment: Only got this error, something like an undefined method?

Comment: You didn't `require` a file for user, you just set it to a string here `const User = "../../models/User";`

Comment: @TheeSritabtim, omg. Thanks!